# Accessing contents inside an iframe on cross domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Hi i wan to access html elements inside an iframe.
This is my code

```
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe"  src='http://someurl.com' width="1200" height="2000">                
</iframe>
var content = $('#myframe').html();
alert(content);
if(content.indexOf("ADD A BOOKING ") !== -1)
{
    //some code here
}
```

but i get nothing in alert
Note:I am trying this on localhost.

Comment: Browser cross domain security prevents this.

Comment: How is this related to `php` as your tags imply?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)